# Whats wrong with the following CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Following is the screenshot :
[image].

As you can see that one `<div>` is overlapping the other `<div>`. Why is this happening ? Following is the HTML Code snippet for the page :

```
<div class="rightDiv">
        <div class="mainCatDiv">
            @foreach (var cat in Model.SubCategories)
            {
                <div class="catDiv">
                    <h2>@Html.ActionLink(cat.CategoryName, "Catalog", "Browse", new { id = cat.CategoryName }, null)</h2>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="productCat">

        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS code for these `<div>'s`

```
div.rightDiv { float:right; width:750px; }
div.mainCatDiv { width:100%;  padding:0px 0 0 70px; }
div.catDiv { float:left; width:320px; min-height:50px; padding-left:30px; }
div.productCat { background-color:#333; height:33px; width:100%;  }
```

Comment: Div.catDiv has only 320px width.So, sub1Cat1 and Sub2Cat1 will merge.

Comment: I think you need to clear after you use float(div.rightDiv and div.mainCatDiv)

Comment: From the screenshot, I cannot tell what is overlapping.  Please provide some more details about the appearance you expect.

Comment: Consider using a simple menu pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/jejNy/

Comment: WHen asking for CSS/HTML help, it's best to post the actual rendered HTML and CSS--not the back end scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to modify your productCat div to include a clear:left, like this:

```
div.productCat { clear:left; background-color:#333; height:33px; width:100%;  }
```

This will force your product div below your category divs.

*Edit: Looks like someone else posted the same answer while I was typing. Best of luck!*

Comment: this seems to have done the trick but i dont understand why. I tried adding `clear:both` in the mainCatDiv which is the parent of floating elements but didnt worked out. Can you explain a bit

Comment: Sure. The floated catDivs are "above" the non-floated elements, "outside" the normal flow, and so your mainCatDiv does appear to have any height because all of its children are floated. Using clear: left (or both) works because it instucts the productCat div to make sure that it has room on the left (or the left and right). An alternative would be to add `overflow:hidden` to the mainCatDiv which will force it to take on the height of its contents. There are lots of ways you could approach this.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your problem correctly, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vA5vy/) should be the fix. You just needed to add a `clear` to `div.productCat`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, `div.catDiv` is too wide, I set it to `200px`, and that seemed to fix it. I don't know if that is too wide or narrow, but you can play with that till it fits your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/EdGGY/1/

css

```
div.rightDiv { float:right; width:750px; }
div.mainCatDiv { width:100%;  padding:0px 0 0 70px; }
div.catDiv { float:left; width:200px; min-height:50px; padding-left:30px; }
div.productCat { background-color:#333; height:33px; width:100%;  }
a{ color: green;}
```

html

```
<div<div class="rightDiv">
    <div class="mainCatDiv">
        <div class="catDiv">
            <h2><a href="#">Catalog 1</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="catDiv">
            <h2><a href="#">Catalog 2</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="catDiv">
            <h2><a href="#">Catalog 3</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productCat">

    </div>
</div>
```